# How to count by groups of IP pairs using shell/bash

Tags: bash, grouping

I need to group a pair of IPs from list below in order to have the totals.

On the list, the first column is the TOTAL of packets on trace from IP-1 to the IP2. I will like to have that after each coincidence print the another flow.

This is the output that I will need looks like:

```
2 66.165.180.244 > 166.210.225.9

3 166.210.225.9 > 66.165.180.244

7 69.20.10.25 > 166.210.225.9

79 166.210.225.9 > 69.20.10.25
...
```

This is my list ordered by first IP, then second IP:

```
 2 66.165.180.244 > 166.210.225.9

   7 69.20.10.25 > 166.210.225.9

  54 72.4.126.205 > 166.210.225.9

  11 93.183.19.220 > 198.228.90.150

 441 93.183.9.188 > 198.228.90.150

  ....

  41 166.210.225.9 > 212.142.237.4

  26 166.210.225.9 > 216.177.212.222

   3 166.210.225.9 > 66.165.180.244

  79 166.210.225.9 > 69.20.10.25

  66 166.210.225.9 > 72.4.126.205

   7 166.210.64.120 > 181.52.246.116

   1 166.210.67.221 > 200.74.148.220

   1 166.210.67.230 > 200.74.148.220

   3 166.210.67.252 > 200.74.148.220

 .....
```

I appreciate your help to have a way to get this order by set of pairs of IPs. I was trying to get by sorting, but do not know how to group the pairs together. I use bash.

Comment: Your input is four columns and you are trying to sort by column two and then four?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, one could achieve the desired output in the following, slightly dirty, way:

- assume that your input is stored in `input.dat`
- replace `>` with spaces in order to unify column delimiters
- add one extra column in the form IP1-IP2, where IP1 and IP2 are lexicographical minimum and maximum of both IP addresses, respectively
- sort according to this auxiliary column (and also according to IP1 and IP2)
- filter this sorted output and keep only records which are duplicit in the last column, i.e., those which correspond to a pair of IP addresses
- finally, get rid of the auxiliary column

In other "words":

```
tr '>' ' ' <input.dat |
gawk '{if($2<=$3){l=$2;u=$3}else{l=$3;u=$2;};
     printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$2,$3, l "-" u}' |
sort -k4,4 -k2,2 -k3,3 | uniq -D -f3 | cut -f"1-3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody can help to improve the script. To have the requested output:

```
2 66.165.180.244 > 166.210.225.9
3 166.210.225.9 > 66.165.180.244

7 69.20.10.25 > 166.210.225.9
79 166.210.225.9 > 69.20.10.25
```

...

I create bellow script, it works, but it is not optimal, because take some delay to process:

```
#!/bin/sh

row=`wc -l traffic.txt | awk '{print $1'}`
i=1
echo -e "#Pkts\tIP1\t\t\tIP2"
echo -e "-----\t----------\t\t----------"
while [ $i -le $row ]; do
    PKTS=`cat traffic.txt | awk '{print $1}' | head -$i | tail -1`
    IP1=`cat traffic.txt | awk '{print $2}' | head -$i | tail -1`
    IP2=`cat traffic.txt | awk '{print $4}' | head -$i | tail -1`
    echo -e "$PKTS\t$IP1\t>\t$IP2"
    a=1
    while [ $a -le $row ]; do
        BUSCPKTS=`cat traffic.txt | awk '{print $1}' | head -$a | tail -1`
        BUSCIP1=`cat traffic.txt | awk '{print $2}'  | head -$a | tail -1`
        BUSCIP2=`cat traffic.txt | awk '{print $4}' | head -$a | tail -1`
            if [ "$BUSCIP1" = "$IP2" ];
         then
            if [ "$BUSCIP2" = "$IP1" ] ;
                then
                        echo -e "$BUSCPKTS\t$BUSCIP1\t>\t$BUSCIP2"
            fi
            fi
            a=`expr $a + 1`
    done
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    echo
done
```

Maybe with AWK can run better, but I do not have so much experience with this one. Cannot use GAWK in machine.

Thanks.